# Expand $a^5 + b^5 + c^5$ in terms of Schur polynomials

Tags: polynomials, integer-partitions, symmetric-polynomials

How to expand certain sums of powers in terms of Schur polyomials.  I have been gaining proficiency with symmetric polynomials, today I would like to expand:

$$ a^5 + b^5 + c^5 = \sum_{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 5} s_\lambda (a,b,c) \tag{$*$} $$

My first take is to write out all the partition of 5 into three parts, and I am going to write them both as sums and as "Frobenius partitions"

- $5 = 5 + 0 + 0 = (4|0)$
- $5 = 4 + 1 + 0 = (3|1)$
- $5 = 3 + 1 + 1 = (2|2)$
- $5 = 2 + 2 + 1 = (2,0|1,0)$ (not sure about this one)

So now I am going to write out all these determinants in terms of elementary symmetric functions:

$$ s_{5,0,0}(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{\Delta} \left|
\begin{array}{lll} a^7 & b^7 & c^7 \\
a & b & c \\
1 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right| $$

$$ s_{4,1,0}(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{\Delta} \left|
\begin{array}{lll} a^6 & b^6 & c^6 \\
a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right| $$

$$ s_{3,1,1}(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{\Delta} \left|
\begin{array}{lll} a^5 & b^5 & c^5 \\
a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
a & b & c \end{array} \right| $$

$$ s_{2,2,1}(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{\Delta} \left|
\begin{array}{lll} a^4 & b^4 & c^4 \\
a^3 & b^3 & c^3 \\
a & b & c \end{array} \right| $$

I am still working out what the Jacobi-Trudi identities say in these circumstances.  In any case, there seem to be 4 Schur polynomials that I need (at this moment) and wish to do the expansion at $(*)$.

Comment: On page $315$ of Enumerative Combinatorics (Vol 2) (R.P.Stanley), the Schur functions are given as linear combinations of the monomial symmetric functions.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I don't have a copy of that book.  Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: Shall I write the seven equations out for you ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: See  here http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit All I need is the expansion of $a^5 + b^5 + c^5$

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
s_{11111} &=& m_{11111} \\
s_{2111} &=& 4m_{11111}+m_{2111} \\
s_{221} &=& 5m_{11111}+2m_{2111}+m_{221} \\
s_{311} &=& 6m_{11111}+3m_{2111}+m_{221}+m_{311} \\
s_{32} &=& 5m_{11111}+3m_{2111}+2m_{221}+m_{311}+m_{32} \\
s_{41} &=& 4m_{11111}+3m_{2111}+2m_{221}+2m_{311}+m_{32}+m_{41} \\
s_{5} &=&  m_{11111}+m_{2111}+m_{221}+m_{311}+m_{32}+m_{41}+m_{5} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Ooops!  I left out 4 equations... if you take a matrix inverse... then you can solve for $m_5$ in terms of $s_\lambda$.  You should post an answer!

Answer (score 1):

The power sum symmetric function $p_n$ is the **alternating sum of hooks of size $n$**, that is:
$$p_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{i}s_{(n-i,1^{i})}$$

Comment: Then $p_5 = s_{5} - s_{41} + s_{311} - s_{2111} + s_{11111} $ ?  Sounds like this is even true in four variables (or more).

Comment: Yes, for 2 or more. See here also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157577/why-are-the-power-symmetric-functions-sums-of-hook-schur-functions-only

Comment: See section 2 here :   https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06569.pdf

Comment: This is certainly not obvious.  I was expecting a more elementary derivation... These resources are great!